# MIDI in VB within Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: vb.net

I know this a trivial (or is it?) but I know I can access MIDI resources in Windows 10 via:

```
using Windows.Devices.Midi;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
```

but how do I access, using Imports, these resources in VB within Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015? Is it, indeed, possible? I have searched everywhere I can think of.

I the meanwhile, I am using Declare Functions to access MIDI components in winmm.dll but I like to to try the Midi resources alluded to above.

I have to move on from this to Android apps and Arduino programming but first I'd like to use the RAD facilities of VB.

Thank you

Sorry, maybe this question is out of place but I am an old lag at MIDI, starting as I did in the 1980s when every thing was so simple on my CBM 64 equipped with 64 KILObytes memory total. 
See:
[Joreth Music](http://www.muzines.co.uk/articles/joreth-music-composer-system/1966)

Comment: They are UWP contracts, you'd use them in a vb.net project that got started from one of the Visual Basic > Windows Universal project templates.  Technically you can jigger a legacy desktop app project to use them as well, but being able to run it only on a Win10 machine tends to be a hangup.  Some day that won't be a hangup anymore.

Comment: Thank you. Running on Win10 only is no problem. This app is only for my use on my machine with my MIDI kit.  I have no legacy apps. I am returning to a topic in which I was very active in the 1980s and 1990s. I just want to access the Midi resouces in .NET

Comment: Back then it was so simple on the CBM64 and AtariST  My FIFO circulatory MIDI IN/OUT buffers were running all the time, ready for the app or the driver to respond. Nothing has changed in the MIDI specification since it was written. However, it appears to have become enshrouded in mystery. Still, for what I want I can use winmm.dll functions